# Get Bitmap orginal size without Out of memory

Tags: android, bitmap

İt is classical question but i didn't find answer for me. I work bitmaps in my project . apply filter,crop.. Problem is out of memory. I need keep many bitmap (approximate 20-30 bitmap) on ram.

I use this method for get image consecutively in gallery, But it is not get orginal size.

```
 public static Bitmap getImageWithoutOutOfMemory(String filePath,int requiredSize) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    o.inMutable = true;
    o.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = requiredSize;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    return img;
}
```

so how can i get orginal image without out of memory exception.

Comment: go for android:largeHeap="true" in manifest

Comment: Where is the OOM thrown, exactly? Does it already happen at the first `decodeFile()`?

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" is working for extra memory. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The function in its current form chooses a size that ensures the image is scaled to be strictly smaller than a required size.
At lease change:

```
if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE) break;
```

to

```
if (width_tmp <= REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp <= REQUIRED_SIZE) break;
```

If the image is 'naturally' with the required size it will actually be returned half size.

If there are other problems please post a MVCE.

Comment: Frankly, that looks more like a comment than an answer

Comment: @dhke I'll answer it up. The poster isn't clear precisely what their problem is but that is definitely an error.

Answer (score 0):

u can try resize bitmap using [decodeSampledBitmapFromResource method](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)